# Booting elementary OS from USB stick on old Dell Inspiron 8200 with Knoppix in German

Tags: system-installation

OK, I apologise in advance for this stupid sounding question but I'm a bit of a dinosaur and I'm in a stoopid situation. That is, my regular laptop which boots with Freya has collapsed in a heap and a friend has lent me an ancient Dell Inspiron 8200 which has Knoppix 7.1 on it. In German. I have the USB stick with Freya on it that I originally used to install Freya on the broken HP laptop. I can't remember the version, but 14 something comes to mind. What I want to do is boot the Dell from the USB, delete Knoppix and install Freya. However, I can't figure out how to boot from the USB stick and everything in Knoppix is in German and I don't speak enough German to figure out what I'm doing. I don't have any admin privileges in knoppix and don't know the password. Can anyone tell me what I can do under those circumstances to boot from Freya on the USB stick? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The 8200 does not have usb 2.0, and does not support booting from usb

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/p/19337400/19715801.aspx#19715801

Your best option will be to burn Freya to a cd rom.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/629785/old-dell-dimension-8200-running-windows-xp

Then:
you can change the boot sequence in the bios, but the f12 boot menu is much easier. Press f12 on the dell logo, it should give the option to boot normally, from floppy, or from CD/DVD. Just put in the Freya DVD, choose to boot from DVD, and then watch the screen for the "press any key to boot from CD/DVD" message, as soon as you see it, press any key on the keyboard and it should boot to the DVD for you.

Source: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21454889/I-have-a-DELL-Inspiron-8200-and-want-to-re-install-but-i-cant-boot-from-CD.html

Finally try a live session to check everything works fine and proceed to install as the only system in your computer. You can let the system choose the partitions by default which is fine.

Comment: Only just saw your reply, thanks, it booted perfectly from DVD